# how to select particular user id in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

i have tried the below code to calculate the attendance of a particular user but calculations is happening for all the users available in the table. I'm new to laravel so i need help.

in the controller:

```
  $TController =DB::table('tbl_attendancetime')
  ->select('username','statusid','status_description','user_id')
  ->groupby('username')
   ->get();  

$TController1 =DB::table('tbl_attendancetime')//->distinct() 
->select('statusid')
->where('statusid','=', 0)//->groupBy('user_id')
->get();


$TController2 =DB::table('tbl_attendancetime')
->select('statusid')//->groupby('user_id')
->where('statusid','=', 1)//->distinct()->get(array('user_id'));
//->groupBy('user_id')
->get();



$TController3 =DB::table('tbl_attendancetime')
->select('status_description')//->groupby('user_id')
->where('status_description','=',3)
->groupBy('user_id')
->get();

$TController4 =DB::table('tbl_attendancetime')

->select(
 'status_description')//->groupby('user_id')
->where('status_description','4')
->groupBy('user_id')
->get();

$TController5 =DB::table('tbl_attendancetime')

 ->select(
'status_description')//->groupby('user_id')
->where('status_description','5')
->groupBy('user_id')
->get();

foreach($TController as $row)
{

$a=count($TController1);
$p=count($TController2);
$e=count($TController3);
$s=count($TController4);
 $su=count($TController5);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first query , in where condition you used this line

```
->where('tbl_attendancetime.user_id', 'create_register.user_id')
```

for this reason, you get all information for the user id which are presented on both   tbl_attendancetime  & create_register.

If you want particular user information, use specific ID.

For example

```
->where('tbl_attendancetime.user_id', 1)
```

Comment: I have removed the join query, And I want information for all the users:                                                                                 ->where('user_id', 1) will give only for one user and another issue is, for one user also it will count the number of days from whole database.